# Is there anything that needs to be done to import system commands like chdir

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I just set up a dual boot Ubuntu on my desktop. This is my first time installing Ubuntu. Everything seems to run fine except for when I went to set up a shared folder. I was running xterm and went to use the chdir command to change directories and got the error "no command 'chdir' found. Is there something I missed when installing unintu

Answer (score 2):

The command is `cd`, not `chdir`.

You don't need to do anything to make this available in the usual shell.

If you *really* want a `chdir` command, you could create an alias:

```
alias chdir=cd
```

If you add this to your `.bashrc` file, you'll get it aliased for all future shell sessions.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error when I try to run sudo mount.cifs. I am trying to share a folder based off of the information in this link http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/

Comment: You'll need the `cifs-utils` package for `mount.cifs` command, it's not installed by default.